# Convert bytes response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, python-requests

REST API call response in bytes, how to convert the data in bytes to dataframe object

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


url ='url_path with_ending_&format=csv'
response =requests.get(url, auth=(user,password), allow_redirects=True)
result = str((response.content, 'utf-8'))
data = StringIO(result)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks fine, do you actually get errors? If not, what's your question?

Comment: Converting to dataframe object gives me the result in one like a,b,c,d,1,2,3,4 etc

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the same issue with Pandas.read_csv();

```
result = str(response.content, 'utf-8')
data = StringIO(result)
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Comment: This is still helpful!